# Vim line between code and line number

Tags: vim

This may seem like a simple question but I've probably spent hours looking for this to no avail. How do I create a colored line on the right of line numbers in Vim? Like this:

[image]

Comment: You mean adding a different background in the line numbers, in order to point out the current line?

Comment: is this screenshot made in vim??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to change the Vim source code for that. Such a patch is unlikely to be included in Vim, though, because one of Vim's design principles is that its features should be available on all platforms, and anything that doesn't fit into the character raster cannot be implemented in the console. (And even workarounds would require special Unicode characters to emulate such a line.)

Unfortunately, you cannot hack something like this with built-in features: Both *sign column* and *fold column* are displayed to the left of the number column. Is that visual distinction really so important for you?!

Comment: Not _that_ important. I have just seen this 3 or 4 times around the web, clearly in various peoples' terminals and went a little crazy trying to do the same thing. I assumed it was in Vim, but who knows, maybe it's Emacs or a cropped Nano or something.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the line, but you can change the foreground color to add some contrast.

From http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_line_numbers:

You can change the color used for the line numbers. For example:

```
:highlight LineNr term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkGrey ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=DarkGrey guibg=NONE
```

Comment: Thank you, I've [already changed the foreground and background color](http://d.pr/i/FmNY) but I can't find anything on the web about how to add a line separator.

Comment: @MikeFunk Try irc on freenode.com, #vim if you don't get an answer on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatrly you can't add a line there: there's no option for that and, I believe, no hack.